# How can I draw a partial ellipse in D3?

Tags: d3.js

I basically want to create a partial ellipse , say half an ellipse , can I do it by using the inbuilt D3 ellipse method , if not then how would I be able to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

To draw half an ellipse by using SVG,
still searching to use d3.
Below is the code for you,

```
<svg>
   <clipPath id="cut-off-bottom">
       <rect height="100" width="200" y="0" x="0">
    </clipPath>
    <ellipse clip-path="url(#cut-off-bottom)" ry="30" rx="100" cy="100" cx="100">
</svg>
```

If you want to know more about how this drawn, here is the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking.

Comment: Ok thanks, But is there any way I could use the values of an array to generate the Ellipse. I dont seem to be able to find a way to loop over the elements of the array.